# If statement in Asp.net Control

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, controls

How would you add a "if" statement inside an ASP.NET control?

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblBeginDate" runat="server" Text='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("beginDate")).ToShortDateString() %>'></asp:Label>
```

If Date is Null set Text to "No Date Selected"

I've tried this but can't get it to work.

```
   <asp:Label ID="lblBeginDate" runat="server" Text='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("beginDate")) != null ? ((DateTime)Eval("beginDate")).ToShortDateString() : "No Date Selected" %>'></asp:Label>
```

--Error I get with my above statement "Specified cast is not valid."

Using Gridview with a dataset as a datasouce that has been populated from a SQL Database.

UPDATE -- Found what I Wanted to do. [Ref](http://forums.asp.net/t/1254412.aspx/1)

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <%if (i == 1) { %>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="If Bloc"></asp:Label><br />
                <%} %>
                <%else { %>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Else Block"></asp:Label>
                <%} %>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

OR

```
   <asp:Label ID="lblBeginDate1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("beginDate").ToString().Length > 0 ? ((DateTime)Eval("beginDate")).ToShortDateString():"Not Selected Yet" %>' />
```

Comment: My statement I've Tried. It says "Specified cast is not valid." if Date is NULL

Comment: It would be better if you set the value in your code-behind instead of in the markup.

Comment: @Ruan, `DateTime` can't be null, since its a structure, that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: @Habib But in the database it's null. (hasn't been set yet)

Comment: @Ruan, then it should map to `DateTime?` , nullable datetime.

Comment: @Habib, oh okay. I'll have a look at that then too thanks. Will also check if I can do it from behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything stopping you from doing this in code behind?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblBeginDate" runat="server" />
```

Then in code behind of this .aspx file:

**C#**

```
// Only cast "beginDate" to DateTime if it's not null
lblBeginDate.Text = beginDate != null ? ((DateTime)Eval("beginDate")).ToShortDateString() : "No Date Selected";
```

And you can continue the logic as needed much easier in code behind.

Comment: `beginDate` is `DateTime`, it can't be null.

Comment: Kind of yes. Since in populating a dataset from the database that contains NULL values in the date field.

Comment: Ill just have to go through my dataset and replace those values then I guess

Comment: You can use `DateTime? beginDate;` to allow for nulls. Or check `IsDbNull` at the point of populating `beginDate` - It depends if your dataset requires Nulls or not? - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I see I have to do it like this, since the data in the dataset cant change. Isn't there a way to do it from the front like this?

Comment: We'd need to see more code, are you just binding the dataset directly to the label? Is the label in a repeater, hence the awkwardness of trying to access it from code-behind?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Gridview with a dataset as a datasouce that has been populated from a SQL Database.
So my ItemTemplate should show "No Date yet" and my EditTemplate should show the date today. So I need 2 Different If statements in one Template

Comment: OK, you can do all this in the code behind still, in the `gridViewId_ItemDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)` event. So you bind the data to the gridview, and then take the itemdatabinding event to do all the decision work. Something like this should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: ah okay That's Neat. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblBeginDate" runat="server" Text='<%# iif(to_char(((DateTime)Eval
  ("beginDate")).ToShortDateString()) is DBNull.Value, "No Date Selected", 
  DateTime)Eval("beginDate")).ToShortDateString() %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: This is still trying to cast a null to datetime, hence will have the same problem

Comment: No, Even after there are no Null values, this code has errors in. (or is it just me?)