# How to use IF ELSE statement in DataBinder.Eval in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have to use multiple if else statement in Grid view if code == "1" then "Test1" and if its "2" then "Test2" and if its "3" then "Test3" and if its "4" the "Test4"..

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code")%>'></asp:Label>
```

so i tried to include like this

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%# if((DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code")).ToString())==" 1" then "Test1" %>'></asp:Label>
```

it shows me error `Invalid expression term 'if'` .. now how to write this , Please help

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295987/if-statement-in-asp-net-control. The solution is using a special if statement (which is not necessary though). More on the if statement can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you should be using the controls `OnDataBinding` event instead and moving any logic outside of your markup into your code behind.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='' OnDataBinding="lblCode_DataBinding" />
```

Then implement the event:

```
protected void lblCode_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)sender;
    string code = Eval("Code");
    switch (code)
    {
        case "1":
           lbl.Text = "Test1";
           break;
        case "2":
           lbl.Text = "Test2";
           break;
        case "3":
           lbl.Text = "Test3";
           break;
        case "4":
           lbl.Text = "Test4";
           break;
        default:
           lbl.Text = "Unknown";
           break;
    }
}
```

It's best practice to keep your logic in your code behind.

Hope that helps.